# One end clamped and other end free cubic spline using scipy.interpolate.splprep and splev

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have the following data:

```
x_old = [  0.00000000e+00,  -5.96880765e-24,  -8.04361605e-23,
    -2.11167774e-22,  -2.30386081e-22,  -7.86854147e-23,
     1.17548440e-22,   1.93009272e-22,   1.49906866e-22,
     9.66877465e-23,   1.48495705e-23]
y_old = [ 0.        ,  0.03711505,  0.03780602,  0.02524459,  0.01349815,
    0.00964215,  0.00972842,  0.0168793 ,  0.02577024,  0.02761626,
    0.02141961]


z_old = [ 0.        ,  0.29834302,  0.59805918,  0.89773519,  1.19755092,
    1.49749325,  1.79750314,  2.09741402,  2.39727031,  2.69726787,
    2.99719479]
```

I want to find the `3-D` spline between these points so that the **initial** coordinate `(0, 0, 0)` remains fixed (clamped) and the other end is `free`.

I did:

```
 from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
 import numpy as np

 # find the knot points
 tckp,u = splprep([x_old,y_old,z_old],s=3.0,k=3,nest=-1)
 # evaluate spline.
 xnew,ynew,znew = splev(np.linspace(0,1,400),tckp)
```

Graph:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax.plot(xnew, ynew, znew, label='first iteration')
plt.scatter(x_old, y_old, z_old, color='blue', label='given')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

**Question 1**. In the above graph, the initial point is certainly not fixed. Mathematically, I know that I need to specify boundary conditions so that I get the 3-D spline I want. How can I do this in `scipy`?. Is there any optional arguments I can use in `splprep` and `splev` that I can specify to achieve this or do I need a completely new way to do this?

**Question 2** : If I wanted both ends to be clamped then how do I achieve that?

*Some Math* : 'Clamped at the initial point' means that the first derivative at the initial point is zero and 'free at the terminal' point means that the second derivative there is zero.

Comment: Isn't this done by double/triple knots?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, but probably I got your question wrong. I remember from b-spline programming (long time ago) that changing knots from, e.g. `x0, x1, x2, ...` to `x0, x0, x1, x2,...` changes the derivative at `x0`. That's not what you want, right?

Comment: No that is not what I need. I need to keep the knot points as is and clamp the initial point (0, 0, 0).

Comment: Well you keep it as is, but give it twice to the algorithm. BTW, what do you mean by first derivative zero?...It is a parametric curve, right?

Comment: I am not giving it twice. (at least that's not my intention). where am I giving it twice?. Yes, it is a parametric curve

Comment: You're not. But depending how `splprep` works, you might, and by this control the derivative at that point. This is useful if you want, e.g. a cubic spline with a kink at a specific point. Giving multiple points reduces an otherwise 3rd order spline to 2nd or 1st order, depending on whether you give the point twice or thrice.

Comment: Since this was mentioned:  `splprep` doesn't allow repeating points, throwing an exception.  Also, I answered  the question as it was stated but frankly, interpreting "clamped" as zero derivative of a parametric curve doesn't make much sense. Clamping would mean the derivative should be set to some nonzero vector which specifies the initial direction of spline curve. (In non-parametric case, we often want horizontal direction, which means zero dy/dx derivative; but the parametric case is different). In any case, this is also possible with the `bc_type` parameter described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want an interpolating spline, which means the smoothing parameter s should be set to 0.

```
tckp, u = splprep([x_old,y_old,z_old], s=0.0, k=3, nest=-1)
```

A clamped spline (or a spline with other boundary conditions) can be made with [`make_interp_spline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html#scipy-interpolate-make-interp-spline). Below, the parameters `l, r` are the boundary conditions at the left and right end. I prescribe zero first derivative at the left end, and zero second derivative at the right.

```
l, r = [(1, (0, 0, 0))], [(2, (0, 0, 0))]
clamped_spline = make_interp_spline(u, np.array([x_old, y_old, z_old]).T, bc_type=(l, r))
xnew2, ynew2, znew2 = clamped_spline(np.linspace(0,1,400)).T
```

Notice that I used the parameter `u` from the first spline, expecting it to perform better than a random linearly-spaced array. (`u` is computed based on the data points.)

Plotting both for comparison:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D as ax
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(xnew, ynew, znew, label='first iteration')
ax.plot(xnew2, ynew2, znew2, color='red', label='second iteration')
ax.scatter(x_old, y_old, z_old, color='blue', label='given')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: splines]

The clamping condition clearly had some effect near that end.