# Smooth spline approximation with fixed start and end points using scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am trying to smooth scaled-up opencv contour segments. I am using smoothed splines and I would like to start and end the spline in actual data points. I am not too familiar with the interpolation and spline fitting terminology, so I do not really know what to search for.

What I would like to achieve is something similar to the red graph below, which is smoothed and I would like to start/end in the same points where the other graphs start and end. I do not mind that it does not pass through the remaining data points, I would rather control the amount of smoothing, but the start and end need to be fixed. Can this be achieved with `scipy.interpolate`? Are there alternatives?

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233842/4556546 which is used for the orange graph, which is pretty similar to the `splprep` version with `s=0`, i.e. interpolation, but this also uses s=0 so I do not see how it helps with smoothing.

I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/32421626/4556546 where the coefficients are manipulated; again, I do not see how it helps achieving my goal. The coefficients resulting from `splprep` with smoothing are already leading to the starting points of the red graph.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev, make_interp_spline

border_segment = 16 * np.asarray([[[2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [2, 11], [1, 12], [0, 13], [0, 14], [0, 15], [1, 16], [2, 17], [2, 18]]])

plt.scatter( border_segment[0].T[0], border_segment[0].T[1] )

# With smoothing s<>0
tck, u = splprep(border_segment[0].T, u=None, s=border_segment[0].shape[0]*16, per=0)
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), border_segment[0].shape[0]*16)
x_new, y_new = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, color='red')

# With interpolation s=0
tck, u = splprep(border_segment[0].T, u=None, s=0.0, per=0)
x_new, y_new = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, color='green')

# With boundary conditions, also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233842/4556546
l, r = [(1, (0, 0))], [(1, (0, 0))]
clamped_spline = make_interp_spline(u, np.array(border_segment[0].T).T, bc_type=(l, r))
x_new, y_new = clamped_spline(u_new).T
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, color='orange')
```

[image: Plotting result from the code above]

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box.
You can try using the weights, `w` to clip the spline at the endpoints. YMMV though.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming that this is not possible, directly! At least I know that I am not missing something obvious. Are you aware of alternative packages, add-ons or scripts that would provide this functionality? Are there any specific words I should be searching for? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [cv::approxPolyDP](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c)? It removes intermediate points depending on specified precision but leaves the start and end points unchanged. You get a simplified polyline and then you can draw a spline through its points.